# Use typescript interface & abstract class without specifying generic types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have created an interface & abstract class along these lines:

```
interface ITest<A, B> {
    testFunc: (input: A) => B;
}

abstract class AClass<A, B> {
    abstract testFunc: (input: A) => B;
}
```

I have multiple subclasses that extend `AClass` and multiple objects that implement `ITest` using various types for `A` and `B`. For example:

```
class SubClass1 extends AClass<number, string> {...}
class SubClass2 extends AClass<string[], boolean> {...}
```

For an abstract class or interface, I assumed I would be able to declare variables that could hold these types without specific generic type parameters, as I just want it to be an instance of `AClass` without regards to the generic types, along these lines:

```
let aClass: AClass; // Could hold SubClass1 or SubClass2
let iTests: ITest[];
```

But I receive an error saying my generic type requires two type parameters. Is the only way around this to set a default type parameter and/or declare these variables with `any` as their generic type argument (e.g., `ITest<any, any>[]`)?

Comment: What values are you assigning to `aClass` and `iTests` that you don't know the concrete types to use? Just to ensure that we give the best answers we can.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited my answer to provide some more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use whatever concrete types are used by what `aClass` and `iTests` refer to. If they're going to refer to different types at different times, then you'd use a union listing the types they may refer to. For instance, if `aClass` may need to refer to an instance of `SubClass1` or an instance of `SubClass2`, then:

```
let aClass: SubClass1 | SubClass2;
```

`any, any` is the worst case where you have no idea at all what the concrete types might be.

You've said you have 10+ of these. If you really need to use a single variable that may refer to instances of any of those 10+ classes, it's probably worth defining a union type:

```
type AnySubClass = SubClass1 | SubClass2 | SubClass3/*...*/;
```

...and then using that for `aClass`.

Comment: I may have 10+ subclasses that extend `AClass`, each with their own unique types. So a union type with that many type options feels a bit dirty, but so does `any, any`. Maybe that's a sign there may be a better way to design what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: @Wrokar - Maybe. (I've updated the answer.) At least with a union you know you won't accidentally refer to something that isn't one of those 10+...